# 2 domains with one SSL cert in IIS7

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, ssl, ip

I have one SSL certificate that is valid for multiple domains. It's not a wildcard cert and it is not for sub-domains. I have the site1 setup properly on IIS7 with the SSL cert bound properly. This binding for site1 maps * IPs with no host header to port 443.

I need to setup site2, a totally different domain, on a new site node, but pointing to the same certificate. When I do this, since I cannot enter the host header, when I browse to site2 and it responds with site1 on SSL. This makes sense because neither binding has a host header specified.

This machine only has 1 IP address, do I need another IP to bind site2 to the same certificate? Should the binding specify the IP address rather than "(All Unassigned)"? Will my solution involve specifying the host header for these sites somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 options.

1. Use another IP as you've mentioned.
2. You will need to manually edit the IIS 7 config from the command line.  I've outlined the steps here:  [link](https://serverfault.com/questions/177484/wildcard-ssl-on-iis7-does-each-site-need-its-own-ip/177497#177497)

Doing this will override the default settings of IIS 7 to allow the same cert to be used on different sites with the same IP.  It's a common step everyone had to take in the IIS 6-7 days.

Comment: Great! Thanks. Would I Need to specify a host header for BOTH sites? Or wildcard for one, and specified for the other? I'm concerned with modifying Site1 because it's live, Site2 is not live yet.

Comment: Specify it for both sites.  So you're going to be running this command twice.  Once with one site's host header info and IIS Site name(whatever you named it), and once withe the other sites host header and site name.  Then in the GUI you can choose the same cert for both sites.  We've done this for approximately 20 sites out of 150 total.  The box uses 1 IP and 1 wildcard cert.

Comment: The following article explains much better than I can.  http://www.sslshopper.com/article-ssl-host-headers-in-iis-7.html